# browserAction opens slowly unless already open in a tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, performance, browser-action

A browserAction in my Chrome extension takes about 250ms to display its popup, `popup.html`.  However, when `popup.html` is already open in a tab in the browser, then the browserAction popup displays almost instantly.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "MyExtension",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-38x38.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

`popup.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div>hello<div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Chrome DevTools shows the tab fully loaded in 2ms.

How do I make it fast?  Can I keep `popup.html` always loaded in the background?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify `manifest.json` to include

```
"background": {
    "page": "popup.html"
},
```

Comment: Do you have any additional information about why or how this improves performance? Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess: When `popup.html` is open in a browser tab or the extension's background page, then it's already in RAM.  Avoiding a disk access should save a lot of time. But a disk access shouldn't be taking 248ms. Maybe Chrome can re-use the compiled javascript/css/html?